# db.collection.find() returns omits keys with no values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am performing a query to show the objects from a specific collection of data in `mongodb` using the query db.collection.find()

On performing the query over a db with collection called `User`, keys with no value are ommitted, hence the length of objects are not the same.

for example:

when I do : `db.User.find()`

I get this for the first two objects :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6be9aba8fced67a9af8154"), 
    "username" : "nestor", 
    "first_name" : "Nestor", 
    "email" : "nestor@example.com", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6bee1767e194695a0a3516"), 
    "username" : "salma", 
    "first_name" : "Salma", 
    "last_name" : "Driss", 
    "email" : "salma@example.com", 
}
```

from the example above, the key `last_name` is omitted in first object since it has no value, but the second one has it present since it has a value. I expect to have `'last_name' : null` if `last_name` value is not present.

So I should expect to get this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6be9aba8fced67a9af8154"), 
    "username" : "nestor", 
    "first_name" : "Nestor", 
    "last_name" : null,
    "email" : "nestor@example.com", 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6bee1767e194695a0a3516"), 
    "username" : "salma", 
    "first_name" : "Salma", 
    "last_name" : "Driss", 
    "email" : "salma@example.com", 
}
```

What query would be useful to help me solve this problem?

Comment: you can either: 1.add the fields, to display null; 2. update the collection 3. create a view. The problem is, if you have a mess of fields on and off, i don't know what can be done

Comment: what is the query you pass in and what is the driver you are using?

Comment: @rags2riches, I did not pass any query in .find(), the main objective was to get all the objects. I am using the result for a different task and requires all keys to be present in every object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can project the result with this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { last_name: { $ifNull: ["$last_name", null] } } }
])
```

Comment: that's what I meant, but the OP just dissapeared. nice answer

Answer (score 0):

The { item : null } query matches documents that either contain the item field whose value is null or that do not contain the item field. [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#equality-filter)

```
 db.User.find( { item: null } )
```

You can also test this yourself by following the link to the MongoDB docs as above.

Comment: This is not correct, if you run `find()` you get all the keys. Presumably, The user doesn't have null values: It has no keys. We'll find out though.

Comment: You do not get keys set to null. You need to pass the query for keys that are null since find will not output them. See the docs and the test.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/

Comment: and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#equality-filter

Comment: `The { item : null } query matches documents that either contain the item field whose value is null or that do not contain the item field.` [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#equality-filter)

Comment: Please consider https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, thank you for your constructive comment. I was not aware of this. Answer edited.